# Mozilla Firefox 36 has problems playing my h264 MP4 files

Tags: firefox, ffmpeg, h.264, mp4

I try to convert videos with ffmpeg to mp4 format (h264) Profile: High Level: 3.1 (1280x720 with 30fps), Bitrate 1500k

The video plays very well in every browser except in Firefox.

http://5.79.72.89/trailer/trailer.mp4

At first it needs longer to load and when I seek inside the video most times the video don't stop to load and never plays again.
I can see a lot of partial downloads in the developer console. A lot of them are for the initial play and the rest of the requests are during the video load when I seek to a later position.

[image]

When I play other h264 Videos (MP4 with similar settings) they play without problems on this server.
And when I put my video on another webserver (apache) there are the same problems with Firefox.

For this reason I believe it has to do something with me my conversion.

My settings:
Debian 7 (wheezy)
Webserver: nginx (with 260k bandwidth limit)

I started converting videos with avconv and switched to ffmpeg because of this problems. But there was no success.
Meanwhile I tried all options for encoding but there are always the same problems with Firefox. Other videos play well but not mines and I don't know why.

Command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -tune zerolatency -x264opts bitrate=1500:vbv-maxrate=1500:vbv-bufsize=3000:nal-hrd=vbr -codec:v libx264 -profile:v high -level 3.1 -movflags +faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p  -s 1280x720 -r 30 -ac 2 -ar 48000 -codec:a aac -ab 64k -strict experimental -y trailer.mp4
```

```
ffmpeg 1.0.10
libavutil      51. 73.101 / 51. 73.101
libavcodec     54. 59.100 / 54. 59.100
libavformat    54. 29.104 / 54. 29.104
libavdevice    54.  2.101 / 54.  2.101
libavfilter     3. 17.100 /  3. 17.100
libswscale      2.  1.101 /  2.  1.101
libswresample   0. 15.100 /  0. 15.100
libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
```

Mediainfo of the file: trailer.mp4

```
General
Complete name                            : trailer.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom
File size                                : 115 MiB
Duration                                 : 10mn 34s
Overall bit rate                         : 1 516 Kbps
Movie name                               : Big Buck Bunny, Sunflower version
Performer                                : Blender Foundation 2008, Janus Bager Kristensen 2013
Composer                                 : Sacha Goedegebure
Genre                                    : Animation
Writing application                      : Lavf54.29.104
Comment                                  : Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 - http://bbb3d.renderfarming.net

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L3.1
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 10mn 34s
Bit rate                                 : 1 500 Kbps
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 30.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.024
Stream size                              : 109 MiB (95%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 132
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=4 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=hex / subme=7 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=12 / lookahead_threads=2 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=50 / keyint_min=5 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=cbr / mbtree=1 / bitrate=1500 / ratetol=1.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / vbv_maxrate=1500 / vbv_bufsize=3000 / nal_hrd=none / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 10mn 34s
Duration_LastFrame                       : -11ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 64.2 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Delay relative to video                  : -2ms
Stream size                              : 4.85 MiB (4%)
```

I don't know what is wrong with my files.

**Update 2015-03-12:**

If I convert the video without audio stream there is no problem with firefox anymore.

I updated ffmpeg to 2.6. I used libfaac, aac and libfdk_aac for audio encoding with cbr and vbr but without success.

Comment: I have the same problem as you, I tried both apache and nginx, and all other browsers have no problem, but FF 36+ has trouble seeking the file and often will never play after first seek. Letting the entire file pre-load allows me to seek, so it has something to do with the way FF handles byte-range encoding. I have the ffmpeg option `-movflags faststart` to move the atom to the beginning, and for the record FF worked great for 2 years, and now all my old encoded videos won't seek either, so it's definitely something with the new FF.

Comment: just to help... i ´ve been searching on the web .. and found that.... maybe will help you. It seems to be a little old but maybe similar (I cannot enter to the video example url from here) 

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1077519

Comment: There are already some bugzilla reports to this bug:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1142455
 
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1145608
 
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1142084

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out this is an unknown bug in Firefox. Your video plays fine in Firefox Nightly.

> See: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1142455

Answer (score 1):

Nothing peculiar on the settings, might be on the output mp4 container.

Try to demux the output mp4 file, then try to mux it using mp4box or similar mp4 muxer. don't forget the flatten/faststart option. See what happens.